# How to merge two images to PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have two images:fon.jpg(CMYK type) and logo.png(transparent bg). 
I want merge this images and save to PDF.

```
    File picture = new File("D://testpdf", "fon2.jpg");
    File sourceLogo = new File("D://testpdf, "logo.png");
    ...
    document = new Document();
    writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(tempFile));
    writer.setPDFXConformance(PdfWriter.PDFX1A2001);
    document.open();
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

    Image imageBG = Image.getInstance(picture.getAbsolutePath());
    PdfTemplate imageBGTemplate = cb.createTemplate(imageWidth, imageHeight);
    imageBGTemplate.addImage(imageBG, origWidth, 0, 0, origHeight, 0, 0);
    Image newImageBG = Image.getInstance(imageBGTemplate);

    Image logo = Image.getInstance(sourceLogo.getAbsolutePath());
    imageBGTemplate.addImage(logo,logo.getWidth(), logo.getHeight(),logoPosX,0,0,logoPosY);

    Image newImageBG = Image.getInstance(imageBGTemplate);

    cb.addImage(image);
    document.close();
```

but have the Error: 
`com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfXConformanceException: The /SMask key is not allowed in images.`

Comment: It appears that you must decide, either you use images with transparency or you want PDF/X conformance. (The **SMask** key refers to the use of a soft mask used for transparency.)

Comment: Thanks, I don't need tranparency, I want merge Images(logo+background) and add to PDF/X-1. Logo is static but background is dynamic.

Comment: *"I don't need tranparency,"* - But you appear to *have* transparency. *"I want merge Images(logo+background)"* - iText *does not* do bitmap image manipulations. The `Image` class can either hold a single bitmap or a form XObject. Your *merging* results in a form XObject with multiple bitmap images. If you really want to merge bitmaps, do that using bitmap image libraries and APIs, and insert the result without transparency into your PDF.